# Reading Garbage with shmget

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shared-memory, garbage

I have created two processes. One of them creates a shared memory chunk and the other tries to read it. There are no compilation errors with this code but somehow Process 2 behaves weird.

Process 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define nDEVICES 3
#define DEVICE_NAME_LIMIT 20
typedef struct d_list 
{
    char d_name[DEVICE_NAME_LIMIT];
    int d_id;

}device_mapping;
int main()
{
    key_t shared_memkey_D=ftok(".", 'D');
    int shared_memid_D=shmget(shared_memkey_D, nDEVICES*sizeof(device_mapping), 0777|IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);
    device_mapping *DEVICES = (device_mapping*)shmat(shared_memid_D,0,0);

    strcpy(DEVICES[0].d_name, "DISK");
    strcpy(DEVICES[1].d_name, "PORT");
    strcpy(DEVICES[2].d_name, "PRINTER");
    DEVICES[0].d_id=1;
    DEVICES[1].d_id=3;
    DEVICES[2].d_id=2;
}
```

Process 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define nDEVICES 3
#define DEVICE_NAME_LIMIT 20
typedef struct d_list 
{
    char d_name[DEVICE_NAME_LIMIT];
    int d_id;

}device_mapping;

int main()
{

    key_t shared_memkey_D=ftok(".", 'D');
    int shared_memid_D=shmget(shared_memkey_D, nDEVICES*sizeof(device_mapping), 0777);
    device_mapping *DEVICES = (device_mapping*)shmat(shared_memid_D,0,0);
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<nDEVICES; i++)
        printf("%s\t%d\n", DEVICES[i].d_name, DEVICES[i].d_id);



}
```

Process 2 is reading all garbage and I cannot figure out what is going wrong after several attempts. Please help.

**EDIT**:

I had copied the wrong program here. I have made the corrections. Its still giving me garbage.

*Process 2 prints the following:*

DISK    11038

?FG+   3

@?FG+   2

Comment: You've tagged your post with "segmentation-fault." Where is the SEGFAULT occurring?

Comment: Please post the output of ipcs -m                                               Also you do not seem to be checking return code, and if you ran this once and it was successful ,each successive run of program 1 will fail. IPC_EXCL will cause it to fail, because you do seem to call shmdt and shmct() to remove the shared memory.

Comment: @Maz - The segfault occurs in process 2 when I try to print the values.

Comment: @jimmcnamara - The code was not successful even on the first time. Before running it again, I free up the shared memory manually using a ipcrm -m call.

Comment: Are you sure the two binaries are ran from the same directory?

Comment: @alk - I am sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* process 1 */
typedef struct d_list 
{
  char d_name[DEVICE_NAME_LIMIT];
  int d_id;
}device_mapping;
```

and

```
/* process 2 */
typedef struct d_list 
{
  char * d_name;
  int d_id;
}device_mapping;
```

are **not** the same.

Change `device_mapping` definition for process 2 to be the same as for process 1, using characters arrays but character pointers.

For process 1 `d_name` uses `DEVICE_NAME_LIMIT` bytes, for process 2 `d_name` uses 4 bytes (32bit) or 8 bytes (64bit).

---

I'd put the common structure definitions into a shared header file, which is included by both pocesses' sources.

Comment: I am sorry. I was trying things out. By mistake I posted the wrong version. I have edited my post. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: I mean its still giving me garbage even after the changes you suggested.